# Show / Hide login menu item not connected to node

Tags: routes

I have a login menu item that links to the login page of my website. I want to have the menu item disappearing when someone is logged in and an a **sign out** button appearing in its place.

Since the menu item is not connected to a node, i cannot alter it's visibility based on node access rights. I found [Menu Item Visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility) module but it is beta and it does not seem to be maintained. Is there a way to do this via Drupal?

If I have to make a custom module or js can you give me a link of a tutorial on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For *login* add a menu item into main menu named as **Login** and path should be `user/login`.

For *logout* add a menu item into main menu named as **logout** and path should be `user/logout`

Now when user will be login then *login* menu will replaced by *logout* automatically. And when he/she will be logout then a *login* menu will appear again.

Comment: Unfortunately the login procedure is handled by a custom module so in order to login I use a different url then user/login.

Is there a way to do this manually?

Comment: if do you want manual work then you must mention in your question.

Comment: you can use this snippet;

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
<?php
global $user; 
 if($user->uid):?>
<li> <a href="user/logout">Log Out </a></li>
<?php else: ?>
<li> <a href="/user">Log in</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>

Comment: Hello WaQar Ali,

I am using TBmegamenu am I suppose to put this code in my php template?

Comment: not in template.php but use this code in page.tpl